# JOIN two SELECT statement results

Tags: sql, select, join, group-by

Is it possible to join the results of 2 sql `SELECT` statements in one statement?
I have a database of tasks where each record is a separate task, with deadlines (and a `PALT`, which is just an `INT` of days from start to deadline.  `Age` is also an `INT` number of days.)

I want to have a table which has each person in the table, the number of tasks they have, and the number of `LATE` tasks they have (if any.)

I can get this data in separate tables easily, like so:

```
SELECT ks, COUNT(*) AS '# Tasks' FROM Table GROUP BY ks
```

returning data like:

```
ks        # Tasks
person1   7
person2   3
```

and then I have:

```
SELECT ks, COUNT(*) AS '# Late' FROM Table WHERE Age > Palt GROUP BY ks
```

which returns:

```
ks        # Late
person1   1
person2   1
```

And I want to join the results of these two `select` statements (by the `KS`)

I'm trying to avoid using a temp table, but if that's the only practical way to do this, I'd like to know more about using temp tables in this fashion.

I also tried to do some kind of `count()` of rows which satisfy a conditional, but I couldn't figure out how to do that either.  If it's possible, that would work too.

Addendum:
Sorry, I want my results to have columns for `KS`, `Tasks`, and `Late`

```
KS        # Tasks   # Late
person1   7         1
person2   3         1
person3   2         0  (or null)
```

Additionally, I want a person to show up even if they have no late tasks.

`SUM(CASE WHEN Age > Palt THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Late`
works well, thanks for this answer!

Two select statements also work, using a `LEFT JOIN` to join them also works, and I understand now how to join multiple `select`s in this fashion

Comment: You haven't given an example of the expected result.  Some answer are therefore concatenating results.  Some are joining.  Which one do you want?

Comment: Sorry, I want my results to have columns for KS, Tasks, and Late

    KS        # Tasks   # Late
    person1   7         1
    person2   3         1
    person3   2         0  (or null)

Additionally, I want a person to show up even if they have no late tasks.

Currently achieving this using the two select statement method with a LEFT JOIN (as opposed to the suggested INNER JOIN, which works but doesn't show persons with no late tasks because they don't exist in the second SELECT

Also achieving this with the late column being
SUM(CASE WHEN Age > Palt THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Late

Answer (score 412, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.ks, t1.[# Tasks], COALESCE(t2.[# Late], 0) AS [# Late]
FROM 
    (SELECT ks, COUNT(*) AS '# Tasks' FROM Table GROUP BY ks) t1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT ks, COUNT(*) AS '# Late' FROM Table WHERE Age > Palt GROUP BY ks) t2
ON (t1.ks = t2.ks);
```

Comment: This works well, though I didn't specify that I want a LEFT JOIN so that records show up even if they have 0 late tasks.

Comment: Accepted this answer because it answers the question I asked best, and it's formatted to be a great reference on JOINing SELECT statements :)

Comment: Excellent answer, but can someone tell is this type of 'solution' considered to expensive or it just depends on what you are using it for?

Comment: @petrosmm I was asking myself the same thing but I guess it comes down to the size of the records and how you indexed your table. Then you should also compare this query to running multiple queries at the same time using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

Answer (score 128):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM
(SELECT ks, COUNT(*) AS '# Tasks' FROM Table GROUP BY ks) t1 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT ks, COUNT(*) AS '# Late' FROM Table WHERE Age > Palt GROUP BY ks) t2
ON t1.ks = t2.ks
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks! I also tried using multiple querys (multiple Joins) and it also woks great. If someone is wondering you can just add more JOINs after the last "ON" in the example, and keep using the sequense:

ON ....
X JOIN
(QUERY N -1)
ON Y = Z
X JOIN
(QUERY N)
ON Y = Z

Answer (score 69):

Use `UNION`:

```
SELECT ks, COUNT(*) AS '# Tasks' FROM Table GROUP BY ks
UNION
SELECT ks, COUNT(*) AS '# Late' FROM Table WHERE Age > Palt GROUP BY ks
```

Or `UNION ALL` if you want duplicates:

```
SELECT ks, COUNT(*) AS '# Tasks' FROM Table GROUP BY ks
UNION ALL
SELECT ks, COUNT(*) AS '# Late' FROM Table WHERE Age > Palt GROUP BY ks
```

Comment: Union or Union All will have only 2 columns in result. Where as he wants 3 of them

Answer (score 22):

If Age and Palt are columns in the same Table, you can count(*) all tasks and sum only late ones like this:

```
select ks,
       count(*) tasks,
       sum(case when Age > Palt then 1 end) late
  from Table
 group by ks
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I wanted, but didn't know how look for it.  I didn't think of using a SUM(CASE) - thanks.

Answer (score 19):

you can use the `UNION ALL` keyword for this.

Here is the MSDN doc to do it in T-SQL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx

UNION ALL - combines  the result set

UNION- Does something like a Set Union and doesnt output duplicate values

For the difference with an example: http://sql-plsql.blogspot.in/2010/05/difference-between-union-union-all.html