# SQL SELECT from a SELECT in JOIN

Tags: sql, select, join

I am trying to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538539/join-two-select-statement-results) answer to do something similar, but I am getting "no such column" error at the first line!

my SQL code is as follows:

```
SELECT product.id, T2.[tt]
FROM product
JOIN (
SELECT reviews.product_id, AVG(reviews.rating) AS [tt]
FROM reviews 
WHERE ...
GROUP BY reviews.product_id) T2
ON product.id = T2.product_id
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Mysql,sql server,oracle?

Comment: Try removing the `[]`

Comment: gonna need it in oracle I think, I am using SQLite atm

Comment: I agree with Mihai: remove the non-standard `[..]` "quotes"

Comment: this did not make any difference unfortunately

Comment: Post the complete error.

Comment: Please check your table definitions, I just tested your code on SQLite and Oracle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/6114b/2 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75533/2 Perhaps the problem is in your  where conditions? Maybe post the whole query or use one of the sqlfiddles

Answer (score 0):

Maybe removing the square brackets and the `as` can help you:

```
select product.id, t2.tt
from 
    product
    join (
        select product_id, avg(rating) tt
        from reviews
        where -- Your where conditions for the reviews table
    ) t2 on product.id = t2.product_id
where -- More where conditions
```

Also, consider not using a subquery. If your query is just like this, you could so something more simple:

```
select product.id, avg(reviews.rating) tt
from
    product
    join reviews on product.id = reviews.product_id
where -- All the conditions you need to define
```

If there are rows in the `product` table that have no matching records in the `reviews` table, but you still want them to be on the result, consider using a `left join`:

```
select product.id, avg(reviews.rating) tt
from
    product
    left join reviews on product.id = reviews.product_id
where 
    reviews.product_id is null
    or reviews.product_id is not null and (
        -- All the conditions you need to define for the matching rows in the 
        -- reviews table
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you currently show in the question (if you remove the [] ) will work in both [SQLite](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/6114b/3) & [Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af42c/1). So it's not displayed above or cannot be seen only by through the query code. Please check the table definitions; it may be a simple as a wrong field name.

Note you haven't displayed the conditions used in your where clause either, it might be in there.

Answer (score -1):

It's happened to me before (in older versions of MySQL if not mistaken). You HAVE to give an alias to every table:

```
SELECT pro.id, T2.[tt]
FROM product pro
JOIN (
SELECT reviews.product_id, AVG(reviews.rating) AS [tt]
FROM reviews 
WHERE ...
GROUP BY reviews.product_id) T2
ON pro.id = T2.product_id
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Not true. At least in MySQL there's no need to define aliases for every table

Comment: adding aliases to subqueries is good practice even in MySQL, and Barranka is correct in some dbms's it is mandatory - but it's not the issue here obviiously