# sql query if a value is 0

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT f.id AS id, 
       c.city AS city,
       ca.category AS cat 
FROM following AS f 
     JOIN cities AS c ON f.city=c.id 
     JOIN categories AS ca ON f.category=ca.id 
WHERE f.member = $this->id
```

The problem is sometimes `city` or `cat` can equal 0. If they equal zero, I can't have them join the cities or categories table, as there isn't a value in the table for 0, nor do I want one.

So essentially I want the above query but I want: if `city!=0` join the cities table, and if `cat!=0` join the categories table.

I don't mind whether I change the PHP or the SQL, but I just can't work out how this can be achieved.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538539/join-two-select-statement-results <- Could turn your tables into select queries. Then you're only joining data that is `NOT 0`

Comment: Surely all you need is a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: You probably mean null and not 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use LEFT JOIN in your query

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is based on the expected output.

If you do not want entries from the `following` table in the scenario that city or category is zero, then you need not bother at all. As you are using `INNER JOINS`, they fetch data from the `following` table only if a record with given city ID or category ID is found.

However, if your requirement is that you need to show empty value when `city` or `category` value tends to 0, then the `LEFT JOIN` shall do the trick.

```
SELECT f.id AS id, 
  IF(c.city IS NULL, 'NO CITY', c.city) AS city,
  IF(ca.category IS NULL, 'NO CATEGORY', ca.category) AS cat 
FROM following AS f 
LEFT JOIN cities AS c ON (f.city=c.id) 
LEFT JOIN categories AS ca ON (f.category=ca.id)
WHERE f.member = $this->id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use if condition to check the value of city and cat before applying join condition:

```
SELECT f.id AS id, c.city AS city,ca.category AS cat 
FROM following AS f 
JOIN cities AS c ON if(f.city!=0,f.city=c.id,0=1)
JOIN categories AS ca ON if(ca.id!=0,f.category=ca.id,0=1)
```