# Combine multiple select queries result in one table or query

Tags: ms-access-2007

hello I have 3 select queries
I want to combine these queries and get result into columns not in rows.
If I use union it will show the output in rows
I don't want these result in column not in row.
[queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPH99.png)

Comment: Already answered here, [join 2 select statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538539/join-two-select-statement-results)

Comment: I have edited the question. Please look at image. Thanks

Comment: @JehoiadaE.Mendoza doesn't seem so, looks like OP is looking for appending columns from 3 select statements and not join in terms of rows. Prashant: can you please provide some examples of what you are trying to achieve. Do take a look at our [how-to-ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this skeleton:

```
SELECT 
    Count(*) AS FirstCount,
    (Select Count(*) As SecondCount From SecondTable) AS SecondCount,
    (Select Count(*) As ThirdCount From ThirdTable) AS ThirdCount,
FROM 
    FirstTable;
```