# How to unify two SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have two `SQL` queries, both of them are working separately, but when I try to unify hem, I have only problems

Query 1 :

```
SELECT Day( funct_consumatori.timestamp ) AS numar_zi, ROUND( SUM( funct_consumatori.timp_functionare ) /3600 ) AS ore_functionare, ROUND( ROUND( SUM( funct_consumatori.timp_functionare ) /3600 ) * consumatori.kwh, 3 ) AS consum, ROUND( ROUND( ROUND( SUM( funct_consumatori.timp_functionare ) /3600 ) * consumatori.kwh, 3 ) * pret_energie.pret, 2 ) AS estimare
FROM funct_consumatori
INNER JOIN consumatori ON consumatori.id = funct_consumatori.consumator
INNER JOIN pret_energie ON pret_energie.id =1
WHERE Year( funct_consumatori.timestamp ) = Year(
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
AND Month( funct_consumatori.timestamp ) = Month(
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
GROUP BY numar_zi DESC
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT Day( ambienta.timestamp ) AS numar_zi, TRUNCATE( AVG( temperatura ) , 1 ) AS temp_med, MIN( temperatura ) AS temp_min, MAX( temperatura ) AS temp_max, TRUNCATE( AVG( umiditate ) , 1 ) AS umid_medie
FROM ambienta
INNER JOIN consumatori AS c2 ON c2.id = '1'
INNER JOIN pret_energie AS pe ON pe.id = '1'
WHERE Year( ambienta.timestamp ) = Year(
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
AND Month( ambienta.timestamp ) = Month(
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
GROUP BY numar_zi DESC
```

How can I unify them based on `numar_zi`(INNER one)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538539/join-two-select-statement-results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your table and data but following SQL might work

```
select q1.numar_zi
        ,q1.ore_functionare
        ,q1.consum
        ,q1.estimare
        -- value of q2 start 
        ,q2.numar_zi
        ,q2.temp_med
        ,q2.temp_min
        ,q2.temp_max
        ,q2.umid_medie
from 
    (
    SELECT Day( funct_consumatori.timestamp ) AS numar_zi
    , ROUND( SUM( funct_consumatori.timp_functionare ) /3600 ) AS ore_functionare
    , ROUND( ROUND( SUM( funct_consumatori.timp_functionare ) /3600 ) * consumatori.kwh, 3 ) AS consum
    , ROUND( ROUND( ROUND( SUM( funct_consumatori.timp_functionare ) /3600 ) * consumatori.kwh, 3 ) * pret_energie.pret, 2 ) AS estimare
    FROM funct_consumatori
    INNER JOIN consumatori ON consumatori.id = funct_consumatori.consumator
    INNER JOIN pret_energie ON pret_energie.id =1
    WHERE Year( funct_consumatori.timestamp ) = Year(
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
    AND Month( funct_consumatori.timestamp ) = Month(
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
    GROUP BY numar_zi DESC
    ) q1

INNER JOIN

    (
    SELECT Day( ambienta.timestamp ) AS numar_zi
    , TRUNCATE( AVG( temperatura ) , 1 ) AS temp_med
    , MIN( temperatura ) AS temp_min
    , MAX( temperatura ) AS temp_max
    , TRUNCATE( AVG( umiditate ) , 1 ) AS umid_medie
    FROM ambienta
    INNER JOIN consumatori AS c2 ON c2.id = '1'
    INNER JOIN pret_energie AS pe ON pe.id = '1'
    WHERE Year( ambienta.timestamp ) = Year(
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
    AND Month( ambienta.timestamp ) = Month(
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
    GROUP BY numar_zi DESC
    ) q2
on
    q1.numar_zi = q2.numar_zi
```

Please make the change according to your RDMS(if necessary), but remember if you want to join two query use the following query

```
select t1.Id, t1.Col1, t1.Col2, t2.Id, t2.Col1, t2.Col2 
from 
    (SELECT Id, COUNT(*) AS Col1, Col2 FROM Table2 GROUP BY Id) t1
INNER JOIN -- or, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, FULL OUTER JOIN .... 
    (SELECT Id, COUNT(*) AS Col1, Col2 FROM Table2 GROUP BY Id) t2
on
    t1.Id= t2.Id
```

Comment: Code is working well but the problem is that I have only 2 rows, in fact the `INNER` query from table `ambienta` has 2 results and the `funct_consumatori`query has 31 (last days of current month) so what can i do to take all data from the table with complete data for every day and if in other table exist data for same day, to assign to current table?

Comment: It is ok, I had to just use `RIGHT JOIN` and some small modifications, thanks alot Raihan, You have my upvote!