# I PHP + MySql noob) How to select data in mysql for query

Tags: php, mysql, web

User send to site acesskey, in MySql in table users there is his data(id, name, acesskey, friends). How to select he ID and echo from table messages all message where id_from = id?

Comment: if your input is acesskey then your search criteria should contain acesskey, not id.

Comment: I try $id = mysqli_query( $dbc, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE acesskey=$acesskey"); And echo $id

Comment: can you explain what exactly you want to display and from where you will get it?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/p2Wsv Its image my tables. I need get from users ID by acesskey and search messages from this ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to combine 2 select query results. Try looking at this. It might explain everything.

[JOIN two SELECT statement results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538539/join-two-select-statement-results)

Comment: I get data. How to correct display this data? I have 2 data from 1 table, while($row = $from->fetch()) {  
    echo $row['name'] . "\n";  
}
It code give only 1 data

Comment: Try something like this.
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }