# How can i join two tables after filtering

Tags: mysql, sql, join, filter, where-clause

How can i join two tables after filtering each table with some condition and on getting the result of filter, join both the results.

Tried code but showing syntax error

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE flag1 = 0  
JOIN SELECT * 
     FROM TABLE2 
     where flag2 = 0 on Table1.email = TABLE2.email
```

Comment: `select ...  from t1 join t2 on ... where...`, i.e. only one WHERE per SELECT.

Comment: @jarlh Sorry but I don't want this. I have some timecomplexity issue by using join on whole table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JOIN two SELECT statement results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538539/join-two-select-statement-results)

Comment: What's wrong with my advice? That's the way it's supposed to be done.

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava - It's that simple. Put the where after the on clause. DBs are clever now. They'll see what to filter and then join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the two Select Statements as SUBQUERIES, and the results of these two subqueries as two different tables and then try joining.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM Table1 where flag1 = 0) Table1 
JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM TABLE2 where flag2 = 0) Table2 
on Table1.orderlist_email = TABLE2.email
```

Answer (score 2):

There may not be enough (RAM/cache) space to save your filtered results and then join them together. It can be slower than you expect.

*technically you can, but not that efficient.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Table1 where flag1 = 0
) A
JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM TABLE2 where flag2 = 0
) B 
ON A.orderlist_email = B.email;
```

however, I'd recommend just join them first, and where everything later. MySQL (or whatever sql engine) will (usually) do a fine job optimizing it for you.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
JOIN TABLE2 
ON A.orderlist_email = B.email
WHERE Table1.flag1 = 0 
AND TABLE2.flag2 = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *  
FROM Table1 as t1
join Table2 as t2 on t1.orderlist_email = t2.email
where flag1 = 0 
and flag2 = 0
```

Correct join will be like this.

Comment: Where is flag2?

Comment: @Sami: majorly answer was related to join and where clause. Anyway I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, this ought to be pretty straightforward. Pseudo-code, but you can solve this a few ways...

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   Table1 
   JOIN TABLE2 ON Table1.orderlist_email = TABLE2.email
   Table1.flag1 = 0 
   AND TABLE2.flag2 = 0
```

Alternatively, you can add the `WHERE` conditions to the `JOIN` like so:

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   Table1 
   JOIN TABLE2 ON Table1.orderlist_email = TABLE2.email
   AND Table1.flag1 = 0 
   AND TABLE2.flag2 = 0
```

I think your concern is whether or not this means the engine will still perform a full scan of both tables, rather than sticking with a "pre-filtered" set it will attempt to join. Modern engines should be clever enough to figure this stuff out, but based on the complexity of your query, your mileage might vary.