# SQL merge sum selects to one result

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have 2 select queries against the same table which both contain only a `sum()` inside the select part, but differ in the `where` clause. What I need to do, is to sum the result of both the queries.

Example queries:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) 
FROM EXAMPLETABLE
WHERE  IDATE BETWEEN '2017/01/01' AND '2017/12/31' AND SOMESTATUS = 0

SELECT SUM(otherAmount) 
FROM EXAMPLETABLE
WHERE  IDATE BETWEEN '2018/01/01' AND '2018/12/31' AND SOMESTATUS = 1
```

What I need is something like

```
SELECT SUM(amount+otherAmount)
FROM EXAMPLETABLE
```

where `amount` and `otherAmount` are selected as in my example queries.

I tried to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538539/join-two-select-statement-results), but I couldn't get it to work. I also tried to replace the fields with a `sub-select`, but this doesn't work, because `selects` are not allowe inside an `aggregate function`

Comment: MS SQL, will add as tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT SUM(case when IDATE BETWEEN '2017/01/01' AND '2017/12/31' AND SOMESTATUS = 0 then amount else 0 end) +
SUM(case when IDATE BETWEEN '2018/01/01' AND '2018/12/31' AND SOMESTATUS = 1 then amount else 0 end) 
FROM EXAMPLETABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an easy way you could do:

```
SELECT SUM(b.a)
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(amount) a
    FROM EXAMPLETABLE
    WHERE IDATE BETWEEN '2017/01/01'
            AND '2017/12/31'
        AND SOMESTATUS = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT SUM(otherAmount) a
    FROM EXAMPLETABLE
    WHERE IDATE BETWEEN '2018/01/01'
            AND '2018/12/31'
        AND SOMESTATUS = 1
    ) AS b
```

I just created a union between the two queries and sum the result.

Comment: could you please explain how this works? from my test i'd say it does work as i need it, but i sadly don't understand how

Comment: Sure! Basically union all results of your both queries in one by using the command UNION ALL (note: you could use only UNION but it will hide equal results) and then I use these two queries as a subqueries by inserting it after a new FROM and between parenthesis and I called it as 'b'  then, the main query just sum it. What is your error? What you happening?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, that with this query I would iterate through the table 2 times?

Answer (score 0):

Very simply :

```
SELECT SUM((1-SOMESTATUS)*amount + SOMESTATUS*(otherAmount))
FROM EXAMPLETABLE
WHERE IDATE BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
```

...be careful of your dates. I think you must replace slashes with dashes

Comment: the dates are fine, and your solution wont work for me, because the example queries are just examples and in reality are much more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write this in SQL Server

```
SELECT
( SELECT SUM(amount) a FROM EXAMPLETABLE WHERE IDATE BETWEEN '2017/01/01' AND '2017/12/31' AND SOMESTATUS = 0 )
+
( SELECT SUM(otherAmount) a FROM EXAMPLETABLE WHERE IDATE BETWEEN 2018/01/01' AND '2018/12/31' AND SOMESTATUS = 1 )
```