# Trouble joining two tables from select statements

Tags: mysql, sql

So far, I have written a select statements getting the names of teams and their average scores on home games and the average scores they conceded to the other team.

I have another one for the teams when they are away, where I selected the away teams and their average scores when they are away and the average they conceded.

How could I join these two tables from the select queries so I get one with the team name, average scored home, average conceded home, average conceded away, and average scored away?

Here is my code:

```sql
select home_team, avg(home_score_half + home_score_full) as avg_scored_home, 
       avg(away_score_half + away_score_full) as avg_conceded_home 
from matches 
group by home_team;

select away_team, avg(away_score_half + away_score_full) as avg_scored_away, 
       avg(home_score_half + home_score_full) as avg_conceded_away 
from matches 
group by away_team;
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try with `UNION [ALL]`

Comment: you want to have all the rows together: that's UNION. If you want to add in the same row fields from different tables then JOIN is your friend

Comment: Consider looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538539/join-two-select-statement-results

The answer in this one explains how to create a result set that would, in your case, have the columns:
`Team name, avg_scored_home, avg_conceded_home, avg_scored_away, avg_conceded_away`

Comment: Or see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the result joined ( on the same  row for each team )  you could use the two query as subquery for join

```
select  t1.home_team
      , t1.avg_scored_home
      , t1.avg_conceded_home
      , t2.away_team
      , t2.avg_scored_away
      , t2.avg_conceded_away
from (
  select home_team
      , avg(home_score_half + home_score_full) as avg_scored_home
      , avg(away_score_half + away_score_full) as avg_conceded_home 
  from matches 
  group by home_team
) t1 
INNER JOIN (
  select away_team
    , avg(away_score_half + away_score_full) as avg_scored_away
    , avg(home_score_half + home_score_full) as avg_conceded_away 
  from matches group by away_team
) t2 ON t1.home_team = t2.away_team
```

Comment: They can be two different teams, so how ON clause can be home_team = away_team ?

Comment: @BilalSiddiqui   .. the question seems clear to me .."so I get one with the team name, average scored home, average conceded home, average conceded away, and average scored away"

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for!