# Mysql get different values from same table in one row

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Please, correct the title if it is not clear, unfortunately my English in not perfect, and I'm not sure how to explain my problem in one sentence.

I have a table of songs and one of artists, this is the songs table:

```
|-----------------------------|
| id  | title | artist | date |
|-----------------------------|
| 1   | song1 | 1      | unix |
|-----------------------------|
| 2   | song2 | 1      | unix |
|-----------------------------|
| 3   | song3 | 2      | unix |
|-----------------------------|
| 4   | song4 | 3      | unix |
|-----------------------------|
```

And this is the artists table

```
|----------------------|
| id  | name    | date |
|----------------------|
| 1   | artist1 | unix |
|----------------------|
| 2   | artist2 | unix |
|----------------------|
| 3   | artist3 | unix |
|----------------------|
```

I would like to get a list of 10 random songs and other 3 song titles.
I want to make a quiz where users listen to a song and must guess the title, so I need 4 possible answers, the correct and 3 worng titles.
So the resoult must be this:

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| id  | title | artist_id | artist_name | date | wrong1 | wrong2 | wrong3 |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1   | song1 | 1         | artist1     | unix | song2  | song3  | song4  |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

How can I reach this?
Thank you very much, and please let me know if you need other info.

Comment: 1) Shown data and shown output does not match. 2) This is PIVOT which is not supported in MySQL - emulate.

Comment: Why are `song3` and `song4` in the same row? They belong to a different artist.

Comment: How to chose the 3 wrong songs? (I suppose your table has more than 4 songs.)

Comment: @Akina output doesn't match because I want to retrieve artist name too with a join... I cannot do this with mysql? :(

Comment: @jarlh yes the songs table has more then 4 rows I would like to retrieve wrong titles randomly and different from the right title

Comment: @TheImpaler because I would like to make a quiz where users choose between 4 answers, which are titles of different songs, doesn't matter if the artist of wrong answers is not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you use two querys. One should return the correct song.

```
|--------------------------------------------------|
| id  | title | artist_id | artist_name | date |   |
|--------------------------------------------------|
| 1   | song1 | 1         | artist1     | unix |   |
|--------------------------------------------------|
```

Another could return three random songs

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 3;

|--------------------------------------------------|
| id  | title | artist_id | artist_name | date |   |
|--------------------------------------------------|
| 2   | song2 | 2         | artist2     | unix |   |
| 3   | song3 | 3         | artist3     | unix |   |
| 4   | song4 | 4         | artist4     | unix |   |
|--------------------------------------------------|
```

Then you could put the four records together in your code.

Comment: I though the same, but if I would like to have more then 100 rows, this could need too time...

Comment: @simonevalentini I would recommend cycling through the select statements with a loop in your code. I think that would be the best solution. But if this is what you have to do, check out this answer. I think joining two querys is what you are asking for. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10538604/10958914